# Hypothesis Testing - Statistics - using $X$ or $x$?

Tags: probability, statistics, notation, random-variables, hypothesis-testing

Suppose I have a random variable $X$ and I conduct a hypothesis test with respect to two hypotheses, $H_0$ and $H_1$ (the null and alternative hypotheses respectively).

I find the critical region (the set of values that will lead to the null hypothesis being rejected), how do I represent this set?

Do I my critical region as:  $X > \cdots$ or $x > \cdots$, (for example)?

As far as I am aware, it should be the last one, since this represents the *values* that the random variable $X$ can take. However, I have seen a lot of material use $X$ when describing the critical region and others use both interchangeably, so I am unsure. Any insight into this is appreciated.

Comment: If you are testing the population mean you should use $\bar x$ for the critical region. Otherwise, it might also depend on the variable you are testing.

Comment: By right, $x$ should be used (assuming $x$ is your calculated test statistic and **not** sample mean). Your reasoning is correct. But honestly, it doesn't really matter since the meaning is clear that we reject $H_0$ when $X$ takes certain values $x>\ldots$.

Comment: This is rather like the distinction between an *estimator* (typically a predefined function of the random variable to be observed) and an *estimate* (typically the application of the function to the actual observation).  I would use $X$ when stating the probability that the forthcoming observation will be in the critical region if the null hypothesis is true, and $x$ when stating whether the actual observation was or was not in the critical region.